# WPF vs WinForms Oxyplot Customize Tooltip/Tracker

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, tooltip, oxyplot

I am building a WPF application and rendering a chart using OxyPlot.

In order to maximize the performance of the chart, I switched to `OxyPlot.WindowsForms` and embedded the chart using `WindowsFormsHost`. Source: https://oxyplot.userecho.com/de/communities/1/topics/35-wpf-performance

Zooming is a very important part of the chart I'm rendering, but `OxyPlot.WindowsForms` seems to not have a great-looking tooltip.

**WindowsForms:**
[image]

**WPF:**
[image]

Is there any way to customize the WindowsForms tooltip to look anything like the WPF one? The most important things are the vertical and horizontal line of the point.

Comment: Looking into the source code of the component, it's not really a tooltip, [it's a Label](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/e3c42f7287739a5900e8cb6ecc294d9312ac3a57/Source/OxyPlot.WindowsForms/PlotView.cs#L313). An option could be getting the [private trackingLabel](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/e3c42f7287739a5900e8cb6ecc294d9312ac3a57/Source/OxyPlot.WindowsForms/PlotView.cs#L54) and apply changes on the region of the control (or ideally replace it with a custom label which supports that shape).

Comment: That post is nine years old, I'm just curious, did you test WPF performance for your case and find it lacking?

Comment: @JimFoye I can see the UI differences, WPF has some trouble rendering many points and it glitches a bit sometimes and leaves blank spaces, which is not my desired outcome. I don't appear to have these issues with WinForms. Do you know how I can test the performance any other way? I haven't done any performance testing before.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks! I've looked into it but I can't find any way to modify this `trackerLabel`, there's no public property that exposes it. I'll keep looking and hopefully something comes up!

Comment: If you're seeing the problems, then that's good enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into the source code of the component, it's not really a tooltip, [it's a Label](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/e3c42f7287739a5900e8cb6ecc294d9312ac3a57/Source/OxyPlot.WindowsForms/PlotView.cs#L313). An option could be getting the [private trackingLabel](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/e3c42f7287739a5900e8cb6ecc294d9312ac3a57/Source/OxyPlot.WindowsForms/PlotView.cs#L54) and apply changes on the region of the control (or ideally replace it with a custom label which supports that shape).

Also to draw the crosshair tracker, you can handle `Paint` event of the plot, and draw the horizontal and vertical line based on the center of label.

well, what I mentioned above is just a quick workaround which results in the following:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
private Label trackerLabel;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var trackerLabelField = plotView1.GetType().GetField("trackerLabel",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    trackerLabel = new BalloonLabel()
    {
        Visible = false,
        Parent = plotView1
    };
    trackerLabelField.SetValue(plotView1, trackerLabel);

    var myModel = new PlotModel { Title = "Example 1" };
    myModel.Series.Add(new FunctionSeries(Math.Cos, 0, 10, 0.1, "cos(x)"));
    this.plotView1.Model = myModel;
    this.plotView1.Paint += PlotView1_Paint;
    trackerLabel.VisibleChanged += TrackerLabel_VisibleChanged;
}
private void TrackerLabel_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    plotView1.Invalidate();
}
private void PlotView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (trackerLabel.Visible)
    {
        var r = plotView1.Model.PlotArea;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, trackerLabel.Left + trackerLabel.Width / 2, (int)r.Top,
            trackerLabel.Left + trackerLabel.Width / 2, (int)r.Bottom);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, (int)r.Left, trackerLabel.Bottom, (int)r.Right, trackerLabel.Bottom);
    }
}
```

And this balloon label, which I assume is a good-enough start point:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class BalloonLabel : Label
{
    public BalloonLabel()
    {
        BackColor = SystemColors.Info;
        Padding = new Padding(5, 5, 5, 20);
        ArrowSize = new Size(10, 20);
        AutoSize = true;
    }
    private Size arrowSize;
    public Size ArrowSize
    {
        get { return arrowSize; }
        set
        {
            arrowSize = value;
            this.RecreateRegion();
        }
    }

    private GraphicsPath GetBalloon(Rectangle bounds)
    {
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.StartFigure();

        if (arrowSize.Width > 0 && arrowSize.Height > 0)
        {
            path.AddLine(bounds.Left, bounds.Bottom - arrowSize.Height / 2, bounds.Left, bounds.Top);
            path.AddLine(bounds.Left, bounds.Top, bounds.Right, bounds.Top);
            path.AddLine(bounds.Right, bounds.Top, bounds.Right, bounds.Bottom - arrowSize.Height / 2);
            path.AddLine(bounds.Right, bounds.Bottom - arrowSize.Height / 2, bounds.Left + bounds.Width / 2 + arrowSize.Width / 2, bounds.Bottom - arrowSize.Height / 2);
            path.AddLine(bounds.Left + bounds.Width / 2 + arrowSize.Width / 2, bounds.Bottom - arrowSize.Height / 2,
                bounds.Left + bounds.Width / 2, bounds.Bottom);
            path.AddLine(bounds.Left + bounds.Width / 2, bounds.Bottom,
                bounds.Left + bounds.Width / 2 - arrowSize.Width / 2, bounds.Bottom - arrowSize.Height / 2);
            path.AddLine(bounds.Left + bounds.Width / 2 - arrowSize.Width / 2, bounds.Bottom - arrowSize.Height / 2,
                bounds.Left, bounds.Bottom - arrowSize.Height / 2);
        }
        else
        {
            path.AddLine(bounds.Left, bounds.Bottom, bounds.Left, bounds.Top);
            path.AddLine(bounds.Left, bounds.Top, bounds.Right, bounds.Top);
            path.AddLine(bounds.Right, bounds.Top, bounds.Right, bounds.Bottom);
            path.AddLine(bounds.Right, bounds.Bottom, bounds.Left, bounds.Bottom);
        }
        path.CloseFigure();
        return path;
    }

    private void RecreateRegion()
    {
        var r = ClientRectangle;
        using (var path = GetBalloon(r))
            this.Region = new Region(path);
        this.Invalidate();
    }
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        this.RecreateRegion();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        var r = ClientRectangle;
        r.Inflate(-1, -1);
        using (var path = GetBalloon(r))
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Gray, 1) { Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset })
                e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, path);
            if (Parent != null)
                Parent.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the animated result:

[image]